# Eclipse/Scala(tra) debugger remote

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, debugging, sbt

I am running my Scala(tra v.2.3.0) application using `./sbt -jvm-debug 8000` - and get the proper "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000" - followed by `container:start`. And the container starts, and the app seems to work properly. The JVM used has been set with `jenv local oracle64-1.8.0.77`.

Now when I go to Eclipse and run my Debug configuration, that is

- Connection type: Scala debugger (Socket attach)
- Connection localhost, port 8000
- Preferred launcher: Scala Remote Launcher
- In Scala Debugger tab, "Enable async trace functionality" is ticked

the debugger looks like it is attached, as I get this screen.
[image: My debug window]

However no breakpoint stops, my Variables window is empty, and it looks like a "ghost app".

Any idea about what I could be doing wrong? I seem to have exhausted the usual suspects (but hey, maybe I missed one).